# Blank screen when invoking in applet viewer

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet

This is my first time posting here. 
I am using GUI in java for the very first time while working on some homework. I have started incrementally coding a Italian restaurant menu.

The below code is compiling fine with no errors. After compiling I run applet viewer `Italian.html` and the applet viewer screen only displays a blank window. I am a little confused as I have no errors to work with. Am I missing something simple.

Thanks for any help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Italian extends JApplet {

//Declare and array for a list of Pastas
private String [] pastas = {"Spaghetti", "Angel Hair Pasta", "Tortellini",
    "Ziti"};
private String [] sauces = {"Maranaria", "Alfredo", "Spicy Marania"};

public Italian() {
//Create the base panel for the restaurant page

JPanel i1 = new JPanel();

i1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

i1.add(new JComboBox(pastas));
i1.add(new JComboBox(sauces));
```

### HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Java Applet Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <applet
      code = "Italian.class"
      width = 250
      height = 250>
    </applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"using GUI in java for the very first time"*  So ***DON'T*** use an applet.  Use a frame!  Applets are not for newbies (and if you have a book that says or implies otherwise, delete it off your kindle, or if paper, use it for kindling).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Funny you say that Andrew. Our professor only wants us to use applet. I wish that I could use him as kindling.... jk ;)

Comment: Where do you add `i1` to the `Italian` instance.  BTW - better to call the applet `ItalianMenu` to help avoid any confusion between that and `ItalianLanguage` or `ItalianCar` or `ItalianLover` or..

Comment: I add it here JPanel i1 = new JPanel(); Line12.

Comment: Tell him/her from me (the top scoring provider of both [Applet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers) & [JApplet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/japplet/topusers) answers on SO), that they are a moron who is unqualified to teach.  For them to accept a wage from their educational institution (employer), is theft. :(

Comment: *"I add it.."*  ..in your SSCCE?  Where is your SSCCE?  (There is a not so subtle hint in those comments - I don't waste much time looking at code snippets.)

Comment: I don't think I have the testicular membrane to say that..... :(

Comment: I thought my example was very SSCCE appropriate. I do not mean to waste your time. I will see if I can gather intel on doing this as a frame and go from there.

Comment: @JaysonHartless - it is **NOT** an SSCCE, because it is not complete.  We can't copy-and-paste the code to a file, compile and execute it to reproduce the problem.  It is not compilable.  The point of an SSCCE is that **you** do the work to make it easy for us to **reproduce** the problem.

Comment: You are correct Stephen. After another glance I see that I am missing the closing curly braces. Was that all I am missing?

Comment: Yes, once I tried your code, it turned out it was missing only the two closing braces.  Please include them in future.  Glad you got it sorted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't added anything to the applet for the applet to show on the screen.

Either in your constructor or you init method you need to add the panel you've created to the content pane.

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // Just to make sure
getContentPane().add(i1);
```

Comment: I just wrote and simple add and it worked add(i1). I am still a little confuse and will investigate this a little more. thanks Andrew, Thanks Mad

Answer (score 0):

you shoud add something to applet to make them work.here is a link
http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/javanotes4/c6/index.html which will help you to know applets and graphics.
this eg. will help you which adds different buttons with proper lay out:

```
/* 
This applet demonstrates various layout managers.
The applet itself uses a border layout with a JPanel in
the center, a JComboBox menu to the North, and a JLabel
to the south. The center panel uses a CardLayout.
Each card in the card layout contains a number of
buttons and uses a different layout manager.  The
JComboBox menu is used to select among these cards.
The JLabel reports events as they occur.
*/


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayoutDemo extends JApplet 
                      implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

CardLayout cards;      // the layout manager for the center panel
JPanel cardPanel;      // the center panel
JComboBox panelChoice; // menu for selecting which card to show
JLabel message;        // a message shown at the bottom of the applet

public void init() {

  panelChoice = new JComboBox();  // Set up the menu
  panelChoice.setBackground(Color.white);
  panelChoice.addItem("FlowLayout");   // Add in the names of the cards.
  panelChoice.addItem("FlowLayout with Big Hgap");
  panelChoice.addItem("Vertical BoxLayout");
  panelChoice.addItem("Horizontal BoxLayout with Struts");
  panelChoice.addItem("BorderLayout");
  panelChoice.addItem("GridLayout(3,2)");
  panelChoice.addItem("GridLayout(1,0)");
  panelChoice.addItem("GridLayout(0,1)");
  panelChoice.addItemListener(this);

  message = new JLabel("Layout Demo", JLabel.CENTER);  // Set up the mesage
  message.setBackground(Color.white);
  message.setOpaque(true);  // so background color will show
  message.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,0,3,0));
  message.setForeground(Color.red);

  cardPanel = new JPanel();               // Set up the center panel
  cardPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
  cards = new CardLayout();
  cardPanel.setLayout(cards);

  setBackground(Color.blue);
  getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);  
  getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(3,3));    
  getContentPane().add("Center",cardPanel);
  getContentPane().add("North",panelChoice);
  getContentPane().add("South",message);

  JPanel panel;  // Will represent various cards to be added to the center panel.
  Box box;       // For the cards that use a BoxLayout.

  // Set up each "card" in the center panel to have its own layout
  // manager and to contain a variety of buttons.

  panel = new JPanel();
  // use default FlowLayout for panel
  panel.setBackground(Color.white);
  cardPanel.add(panel, "FlowLayout");
  addButton(panel,"First Button");  // ( addButton is a untility method, defined below )
  addButton(panel,"Second Button");
  addButton(panel,"Third Button");
  addButton(panel,"Fourth Button");
  addButton(panel,"Fifth Button");
  addButton(panel,"Sixth Button");
  addButton(panel,"Seventh Button");

  panel = new JPanel();  
  panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,30000,5));
  panel.setBackground(Color.white);
  cardPanel.add(panel,"FlowLayout with Big Hgap");
  addButton(panel," A Button");
  addButton(panel,"Another Button");
  addButton(panel,"A Third Button");
  addButton(panel,"A Fourth Button");
  addButton(panel,"A Final Button");

  box = Box.createVerticalBox();  
  box.setBackground(Color.white);
  cardPanel.add(box,"Vertical BoxLayout");
  addButton(box,"Button One");
  addButton(box,"Button Two");
  addButton(box,"Button Three");
  addButton(box,"Button Four");
  addButton(box,"Button Five");
  addButton(box,"Button Six");

  box = Box.createHorizontalBox();  
  box.setBackground(Color.white);
  cardPanel.add(box,"Horizontal BoxLayout with Struts");
  addButton(box,"1st");
  addButton(box,"2nd");
  box.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut(10) );
  addButton(box,"3rd");
  addButton(box,"4th");
  box.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut(10) );
  addButton(box,"5th");

  panel = new JPanel();  
  panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  panel.setBackground(Color.white);
  cardPanel.add(panel,"BorderLayout");
  addButton(panel,"Center Button", BorderLayout.CENTER); 
  addButton(panel,"North Button", BorderLayout.NORTH);
  addButton(panel,"South Button", BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  addButton(panel,"East Button", BorderLayout.EAST);
  addButton(panel,"West Button", BorderLayout.WEST);

  panel = new JPanel();  
  panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
  panel.setBackground(Color.white);
  cardPanel.add(panel,"GridLayout(3,2)");
  addButton(panel,"Button 1");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 2");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 3");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 4");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 5");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 6");                  

  panel = new JPanel();  
  panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));
  panel.setBackground(Color.white);
  cardPanel.add(panel,"GridLayout(1,0)");
  addButton(panel,"Button 1");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 2");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 3");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 4");                  

  panel = new JPanel();  
  panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
  panel.setBackground(Color.white);
  cardPanel.add(panel,"GridLayout(0,1)");
  addButton(panel,"Button 1");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 2");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 3");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 4");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 5");                  
  addButton(panel,"Button 6");                  

  } // end init()


 public Insets getInsets() {
    // specify borders around the edges of the applet
  return new Insets(3,3,3,3);
 }


void addButton(Container p, String name) {
      // Create a button with the given name and add it
      // to the given panel.  Set up the button to send
      // events to the applet.
  JButton b = new JButton(name);
  p.add(b);
  b.addActionListener(this);
}


void addButton(JPanel p, String name, Object option) {
      // Same as above, but use the "option" object
      // as an additional parameter in the add method.
  JButton b = new JButton(name);
  p.add(b, option);
  b.addActionListener(this);
 }


 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     // A button was pressed.  Report the name
     // of the button by setting the message text.
  String buttonName = evt.getActionCommand();
  message.setText("Button \"" + buttonName + "\" was pressed.");
 }

 public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
     // The user has selected an item from the JComboBox.
     // Change the displayed card to match.
  String panelName = (String)panelChoice.getSelectedItem();
  cards.show(cardPanel, panelName);
  message.setText("Panel \"" + panelName + "\" was selected.");
 }


} // end class LayoutDemo
```